# VBA Matching Issues

Tags: vba, excel

The following code is used to do matching between two sheets.
It work fine, but it have problem when

for example in sheet 1:  (Notes: I use the contents from the sheet 1 to do matching in sheet 2)

```
Cells(1, 8) value: Rev#

Cells(1, 3) value: REV#
```

In sheet 2:

```
Value for Rev#: 123xyz

Value for REV#: PQRSABC
```

Rev# and REV# is totally a different thing, but the result I get from the program is always "123xyz". Do we have any idea to get the correct result instead of Rename REV# to other?

Thanks for the advise.

```
icol = 1

For icol = 1 To numofcol
    FindString = Worksheets("Temp_A").Cells(1, icol).Value
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(numofrow1, numofcol1)).Find(what:=FindString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If rng.Value = "Process Type:" Then
        If InStr(rng.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Value, ":") > 0 Then
            temp = vbNullString
        Else
            temp = rng.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Value
        End If
    Else
        If InStr(rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Value, ":") > 0 Then
            temp = vbNullString
        Else
            temp = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Value
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: In your .Find add this parameter MatchCase:=true

Comment: Hi Jules, Thank you :) Appreciated.